# How to get html code that looks like on web browser by servlet?

Tags: html, jsoup, servlet-3.0

I need to get the html using JSoup.

I have now:

```
Document doc = Jsoup
               .connect("http://~~~")
               .get();
```

problem : dynamic web site, web lazy load images, nested frames.

I can't get all resources, html code. 
When I connect to the site by jsoup, that site code & resource & html is not complete.

ex) lazy load images : not completed code -> ~~/white.png 
changed to completed code -> something.png

How get completed html code that looks like on web browser.
Someone mentioned use httpClient library. But I don't know what I should do.

Comment: Use something like Selenium or PhantomJS. Jsoup doesn't support JavaScript, as it's only a HTML parser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using **HtmlUnit** framework instead? **HtmlUnit** is better suited for web application unit testing automation and **JSoup** is better suited for Web Scraping.

Take a look at this: http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/gettingStarted.html